# Using enum values defined by COM server in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, com

I have an application that provides a COM interface. In that interface there is a method, which expects an enum value as a parameter.

Calling the method from PowerShell seems to be difficult though. Currently I simply use the integer representation of the enum value:

```
$app = New-Object -ComObject MyApp.Application
$app.MyMethod(0)
```

But this is of course very ugly. What I would rather do is:

```
$app = New-Object -ComObject MyApp.Application
$app.MyMethod(cMyEnumValue)
```

But PowerShell does not know what to do with that. Is there a special syntax to actually use the enum value's name, as it is defined in the COM interface?

Comment: Since enum is just a set of integers, try defining the same [as Powershell's enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: As for this... `But this is of course very ugly.`, there are times where we have to use what we have. ***;-}** Since that is all a given language/solution will provide. Otherwise, you need to get creative as vonPryz is pointing out.

Comment: But what if the enum is changed in the COM interface? Then my PowerShell enum would produce totally wrong results.

Comment: Wait, what? If the parameters change unexpectedly, that would violate design by contract principle. That's bad software engineering practice.